# ImageData to Image to ImageData, in LABColor

Tags: image-processing, color, image

Given an $m\times n$ image $G1$, I'm trying to:

1. Extract the $mn$ pixels of $G1$ as an $n\times m$ matrix $M1$ of triples, where each triple represents the color in LAB space.
2. Turn $M1$ into an $m\times n$ image $G2$.
3. Extract the $mn$ pixels of $G2$ as an $n\times m$ matrix $M2$ of triples, where each triple represents the color in LAB space.
4. $G1$ should equal $G2$, and $M1$ should equal $M2$.

The problem I run into is that $G1$ *does* equal $G2$, but $M1$ does *not* equal $M2$.

Here's a toy example with a random $3\times 2$ image.

```
G1 = RandomImage[NormalDistribution[0, 5], {3, 2}, ColorSpace -> "LAB"]
M1 = MatrixForm@ImageData[G1, "Real"]
G2 = Graphics@Raster[Reverse@M1[[1]], ColorFunction -> LABColor]
M2 = MatrixForm@ImageData[G2, "Real"]
```

Also, when I turn $G2$ into an Image

```
Image@G2
```

I get something entirely different.

Comment: `G1 = RandomImage[NormalDistribution[0, 5], {3, 2}, 
   ColorSpace -> "LAB"];
M1 = ImageData[G1, "Real"]; G2 = Image[M1, ColorSpace -> "LAB"]; M2 = 
 ImageData[G2, "Real"]`